# How to properly develop for android tablets with out ruining icons and text sizes?

Tags: android, xml

I'm developing an app for android tablets.

Before, I had set up my XML like so:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false" />
```

Everything came out fine, the text and icons were regular sizes. But, I realized that this wouldn't because I wouldn't be able to release the app specifically to tablets that are between 7inches and 10 inches.

So I changed the XML to this:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"
                      android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:largestWidthLimitDp=""
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

After doing this, certain text ands icons became very small and hard to read on my 10 inch nexus tablet.

I want to deploy the add specifically to tablets between the sizes of 7inches to 10inches.

Note: I tried setting anyDensity to true as well, it didn't work. Not sure if this information matters or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supports-screen tag in the manifest file is good for defining which kind of devices you allow your app to run on, and as far as that's concerned, you've gotten it right with setting the large & xlarge screens to true (I don't think you need the last two attributes there though).

As for your problem with the text sizes in different devices, I'm afraid that if you truly want your app to look good on devices which range from 7" to 10" on multiple densities, you're going to need to work a little bit harder.

First of all, when defining dimensions of components in your app, you should always work with "dp" type variables, or "sp" when dealing with font sizes ("sp" adheres to the devices text size setting in the settings-->accessibility section). This should solve issues with different densities on different devices.

7" tablets typically require slightly scaled down dimensions to their 10" counterparts, since they usually have less screen real-estate. To solve this issue, you'll need to work with a dimensions file (`<dimen>` tags), and have separate dimensions files for large screens & xlarge screens. This can be achieved by defining the same dimension names in two files with different values, and placing one file in the values-large folder, and the other in the values-xlarge folder.

From my experience, the best results are achieved when the dimensions for the 7" devices are about 75% the 10" dimensions.

Comment: You were correct, I did not need the last two attributes. I took those lines out, and it worked. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, there are `qualifiers` in the resource system. These are little keywords you append to the folder names to specify which configuration this folder should be used for. In your case you should create some folders like:

drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi

So now if the dpi rate of the device your app is runnig on is in the mdpi region for example, the framework will automatically use the images from drawable-mdpi. All you have to do is add icons in different sizes to the folders. Read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html). Also check out this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2pneM9fOJg).

Comment: So what about the text? The text also comes out small for what ever reason.

Comment: You can define a `values-hdpi` and so on with a `dimension` file in each one containing a good size for the text which can be referenced using `@dimen/textize`. Or use `sp` for text size.